# CMake Error, on MacOS, Could not find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY)

Tags: macos, cmake, zlib, azerothcore

when configuring with cmake in order to compile [azerothcore](https://www.azerothcore.org), I am receiving an CMake error where ZLIB can't be located.

This is what I'm getting:

```
Lees-MBP-2:build leeelliott$ export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
Lees-MBP-2:build leeelliott$ cmake ../ \
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/leeelliott/azerothcore/server/  \
> -DTOOLS_BUILD=all \
> -DSCRIPTS=static \
> -DMYSQL_ADD_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/include/mysql \
> -DMYSQL_LIBRARY=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib \
> -DREADLINE_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include \
> -DREADLINE_LIBRARY=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib \
> -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/include" \
> -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARIES="$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/lib/libssl.dylib" \
> -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARIES="$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/lib/libcrypto.dylib"
-- CMake version: 3.27.1
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_LOAD_CONF
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_LOAD_CONF
-- Enabled С++20 standard
-- Detected 64-bit platform
-- UNIX: Using default configuration directory
-- UNIX: Using default library directory
-- UNIX: Configuring uninstall target
-- UNIX: Created uninstall target
-- UNIX: Detected compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Clang: Minimum version required is 10.0.0, found 14.0.0.14000029 - ok!
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_LOAD_CMAKE_MODULES
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_LOAD_CMAKE_MODULES
-- Using mysql-config: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-- Found MySQL library: /opt/homebrew/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib
-- Found MySQL headers: /usr/local/include/mysql
-- Found MySQL executable: /usr/local/bin/mysql
-- Found git binary : /usr/local/bin/git

* AzerothCore revision            : a5e84f610a0e 2023-07-26 11:53:12 +0000 (master branch)
* AzerothCore buildtype           : RelWithDebInfo

* Install core to                 : /leeelliott/azerothcore/server
* Install libraries to            : /leeelliott/azerothcore/server/lib
* Install configs to              : /leeelliott/azerothcore/server/etc

* Build applications              : Yes (all)
* Build tools                     : Yes (all)
* Build with scripts              : Yes (static)
* Build with modules              : Yes (static)
* Build unit tests                : No  (default)
* Build core w/PCH                : Yes (default)
* Build scripts w/PCH             : Yes (default)
* Show compile-warnings           : No  (default)
* Use coreside debug              : No  (default)
* Use unix gperftools             : No  (default)
* Use GIT revision hash           : Yes (default)
* Enable vmap DisableMgr checks   : Yes (default)
* Show source tree                : No (For UNIX default)

-- Found OpenSSL library: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.dylib;/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib
-- Found OpenSSL headers: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.27.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.27.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.27.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:200 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  deps/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have installed zlib using `brew install zlib`

Zlib folder appears to be located in /usr/local/cellar/zlib/

How do I get cmake to recognize/find zlib?

Comment: There's something strange going on with your system. 1) CMake should pick the zlib included with XCode or the commandline tools. 2) you appear to have 2 versions of Homebrew one in `/usr/local` and one in `/opt/homebrew`

Answer (score 0):

According to this line in the formula, https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/7b9a651799694bc869b8bfad80a7782383d860bf/Formula/zlib.rb#L28 the library is installed as keg-only, which means it sits in your cellar but does not get linked into the directory search paths used by cmake.  The reason is to avoid any unintentional conflict with Apple zlib.
To use brewed zlib, you must force the link after installation with

`brew --force link zlib`

Comment: you shouldn't force link. `brew info zlib` gives you all the info you need to use it.

Comment: Yes that would yield another solution.  Force linking is nothing permanent.  There is really no need to use brewed zlib at all on macOS.